# Isomorphism between Riemann Surface and $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface. Prove that if $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, then $X$ admits a meromorphic function $f$ that has a single pole and that this pole has multiplicity one.

Since $X$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ are isomorphic, then there exists a biholomorphic function $f$ between them. This $f$ happens to be meromorphic with only one pole. However, I can't seem to be able to prove that this pole must have multiplicity one. All I got so far is, assume that it has multiplicity greater than one, $n$, then every point in $\mathbb{P}^1$ must have multiplicity $n$. Can someone help me out with where to go next?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The integer $n$ is the number of points in $X$ (counting multiplicity) in the preimage of an arbitrary point in $\mathbf{P}^{1}$.

Comment: Since $f$ is biholomorphic then the multiplicity of every point in X in the preimage of an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $n$. So we got that the multiplicity of every point in $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both $n$. Where do I go from there?

Comment: Let $z$ denote an element of $\mathbf{P}^{1}$. How many points are in $f^{-1}(\{z\})$, given that $f$ is a biholomorphism?

Comment: Only 1 and that point should have multiplicity $n$

Comment: Just asking: What exactly is your definition of "multiplicity"?

Comment: There is a theorem that says every holomorphic mapping between two Riemann Surfaces, when composed with charts can be written as $z^k$. This $k$ here is the multiplicity.

Comment: Ah. Let's suppose there exists a point of $X$ where $f$ has multiplicity $k > 1$. Can you use your definition to show $f$ is not a biholomorphism? (You'll need to think about the behavior of $z \mapsto z^{k}$ in small neighborhoods of $0$.)

Comment: If $f$ is a bijection then composing it with charts is also a bijection. Thus, $z^k$ must be a bijection which is not true.